# Mergesort using map-reduce, multithreads, buffers and condition variables

Tags: c, multithreading, memory-management, mergesort, mapreduce

I wrote a map reduce program which uses multi threads, bounded buffers, condition variables. It works perfectly for some types of inputs.

In the program there are N mappers, R reducers, 1 merger. mappers get data from input files, put each string in files to corresponding buffer-X-Y. reducers read from those buffers, sort the strings, and put each sorted sequence to buffer-Y. merger merges given sequences and writes to an output file.

How I run:

```
make;valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=yes ./program 1 5 file o 10
```

"File" content:

> Take me down to the paradise city
>
> Where the grass is green and the girls are pretty
>
> Take me home (oh won't you please take me home)
>
> Take me down to the paradise city
>
> Where the grass is green and the girls are pretty
>
> Take me home (oh won't you please take me home)

If you make that file content "a a bb bb" it gives different output.

Is there any way I can improve it?

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#define FILE_NAME_SIZE 20
#define WORD_LENGTH 286
// a bit extra to carry "\t(occurance)"

struct arg {
    int index;
    char *file_name;
};
struct listNode {
    char *data;
    struct listNode *next;
    int occurrence;
};
int N;
int R;
char output_file[WORD_LENGTH];
int bufsize;

/*  there are n*r buffers between mappers-reducers. 3d array.
    r buffers between reducers-merger. should be 2d array but
    buffer[N] is allocated for second type of buffers. */
char ****buffer;

// buffer[i][j][0]=fill, buffer[i][j][1]=use, 
// buffer[i][j][2]=count, buffer[i][j][3]=to be inserted in total
int ***buffer_info;

pthread_mutex_t **mutex;
pthread_cond_t **c_fill;
pthread_cond_t **c_empty;

void put(int i, int j, char *value) {
    strcpy(buffer[i][j][(buffer_info[i][j][0])], value);
    buffer_info[i][j][0] = (buffer_info[i][j][0] + 1) % bufsize;
    buffer_info[i][j][2]++;
    printf("put into buffer[%d][%d] '%s'\n", i, j, value);
}

char* get(int i, int j) {
    char* tmp = buffer[i][j][(buffer_info[i][j][1])];
    buffer_info[i][j][1] = (buffer_info[i][j][1] + 1) % bufsize;
    buffer_info[i][j][2]--;
    printf("-get '%s' from buffer[%d][%d]\n", tmp, i, j);
    return tmp;
}

void insert (struct listNode **ptr, char *value) {
    struct listNode *newPtr;
    int cmp;

    // find a place to instert node to LL
    while(*ptr){
        // Comparision to detect & remove duplicates nodes

        cmp = strcmp(value, (*ptr)->data);
        // duplicate
        if(cmp == 0){
            (*ptr)->occurrence++;
            return; 
        }
        // the point where i need to add the node
        if(cmp < 0) 
            break;

        ptr = &(*ptr)->next;
    }

    // now here *ptr points to the pointer that i want to change
    // it can be NULL, if we are at the end of the LL

    newPtr = malloc(sizeof *newPtr);
    if(!newPtr)
        return;

    newPtr->data = strdup(value);
    newPtr->occurrence = 1;

    if(newPtr->data == NULL){
        free(newPtr);
        return;     
    }

    // here we are connecting our brand new node to the LL
    newPtr->next = *ptr;
    *ptr = newPtr;
}

static void *merger(){
    FILE *file;
    char temp[WORD_LENGTH];
    char temp2[WORD_LENGTH+30];
    int occurrence=0;
    int i;
    char *tok;

    // once we have the element that comes first we will put write it to file.
    file = fopen(output_file, "w");
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // first element (according to asc order) in each file will be here
    // we will use this array to find the next string to write to output
    char child_heads[R][WORD_LENGTH];
    int child_heads2[R];

    // when there is no string left in a temp, we will
    // describe it here. value 1 means we are done.
    int child_done[R];

    for(i = 0; i<R; i++){
        child_done[i] = 0;

        // printf("buffer_info[%d][%d][3]: %d\n", N, i, buffer_info[N][i][3]);
        if(buffer_info[N][i][3] != 0){
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex[N][i]); 
            while (buffer_info[N][i][2] == 0) 
                pthread_cond_wait(&c_fill[N][i], &mutex[N][i]); 
            strcpy(temp2, get(N, i));
            buffer_info[N][i][3]--;
            pthread_cond_signal(&c_empty[N][i]); 
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex[N][i]); 

            tok = strtok(temp2, "\t");
            strcpy(temp, tok);
            while((tok = strtok(NULL, "\t")))
                occurrence=atoi(tok);

            strcpy(child_heads[i], temp);
            child_heads2[i] = occurrence;               
        } else {
            child_done[i] = 1;
        }

        // printf("%d.%d\n", i, child_done[i]);
    }

    int done;
    int min_i = -1;

    while(1){

        min_i = -1;

        done = 1;

        // comparisons are not started, we assign the first available
        // item as the minimum for comparisons.
        if(min_i == -1){
            for(i=0; i<R; i++){
                if(child_done[i]==0){
                    min_i = i;
                    break;
                }               
            }
        }

        for(i=0; i<R; i++){
            if(child_done[i]==0 && strcmp(child_heads[i],child_heads[min_i])<0){
                min_i = i;
            }

            // if all data in all files are read stop the outer loop
            if(child_done[i] == 0){
                done = 0;               
            }
        }

        if(done == 1){
            break;
        }

        // write the element into the file
        fprintf(file, "%s\t%d\n", child_heads[min_i], child_heads2[min_i]);

        // so we used the string that comes first in heads, 
        // now we'll update that element's place in heads array.

        if(buffer_info[N][min_i][3] != 0){
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex[N][min_i]); 
            while (buffer_info[N][min_i][2] == 0) 
                pthread_cond_wait(&c_fill[N][min_i], &mutex[N][min_i]); 
            strcpy(temp2, get(N, min_i));
            buffer_info[N][min_i][3]--;
            pthread_cond_signal(&c_empty[N][min_i]); 
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex[N][min_i]); 

            tok = strtok(temp2, "\t");
            strcpy(temp, tok);
            while((tok = strtok(NULL, "\t")))
                occurrence=atoi(tok);

            strcpy(child_heads[min_i], temp);
            child_heads2[min_i] = occurrence; 
        } else {
            // there is no element coming from the temp
            child_done[min_i] = 1;          
        }

    }

    // close temp files
    fclose(file);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

static void *reducer(void *arg){
    int index=*((int*)arg);

    // printf("--- reducer %d here!\n", index);

    char temp[WORD_LENGTH];
    char temp2[WORD_LENGTH+30];
    strcpy(temp, "");
    strcpy(temp2, "");
    int j, k;
    struct listNode *head = NULL;

    // read from buffer
    for(j=0; j<N; j++){
        for(k=0; k<buffer_info[j][index][3]; k++){
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex[j][index]); 
            while (buffer_info[j][index][2] == 0) 
                pthread_cond_wait(&c_fill[j][index], &mutex[j][index]); 
            strcpy(temp, get(j, index));
            pthread_cond_signal(&c_empty[j][index]); 
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex[j][index]); 

            insert(&head, temp);    
        }
    }

    // this buffer must carry a sorted sequence.
    // when there is no items left to send, then merger must be notified
    // how to know when there is no items left to send?
    // her buffer[i][j] için 

    // write to buffer
    struct listNode *ptr = head;
    while (ptr){
        sprintf(temp2, "%s\t%d", ptr->data, ptr->occurrence);

        // write word to a buf.
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex[N][index]); 
        while (buffer_info[N][index][2] == bufsize) 
            pthread_cond_wait(&c_empty[N][index], &mutex[N][index]); 
        // see buffer definition to understand why (N) is here
        put(N, index, temp2);
        buffer_info[N][index][3]++;
        pthread_cond_signal(&c_fill[N][index]); 
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex[N][index]); 

        // printf("Reducer %d - %d.%s\t%d\n", index, i, ptr->data, ptr->occurrence);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }

    // deallocations
    while (head){
        ptr = head;
        head = head->next;
        free(ptr->data);
        free(ptr);
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

static void *mapper(void *arg_ptr){
    // printf("mapper %s here!\n", ((struct arg *) arg_ptr)->file_name);
    int bytes;
    int j, i;
    i = ((struct arg *) arg_ptr)->index;

    // read input file
    char temp[WORD_LENGTH];
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen(((struct arg *) arg_ptr)->file_name, "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file: %s\n", ((struct arg *) arg_ptr)->file_name);
        return NULL;
    } 

    // scan the next %s from stream and put it to temp
    while(fscanf(file, "%s", temp) > 0){
        bytes = 0; 
        int k;
        for(k=0; k<strlen(temp)+1; k++){
            bytes += temp[k];
        }
        j = bytes % R;

        // write word to a buf.
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex[i][j]); 
        while (buffer_info[i][j][2] == bufsize) 
            pthread_cond_wait(&c_empty[i][j], &mutex[i][j]); 
        put(i, j, temp);
        buffer_info[i][j][3]++;
        pthread_cond_signal(&c_fill[i][j]); 
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex[i][j]); 

        // good luck understanding :) 
    }

    fclose(file);


    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    printf("_______________________________________\n");

    int i, j, k, ret;

    // program inputs: <N> <R> <infile1> … <infileN> <finalfile> <bufsize>
    N = atoi(argv[1]); // atoi = ascii to int
    R = atoi(argv[2]);
    char input_files[N][WORD_LENGTH];
    for(i=0; i<N; i++){
        strcpy(input_files[i], argv[3+i]);
    }
    strcpy(output_file, argv[3+N]);
    bufsize = atoi(argv[4+N]);
    if(bufsize>10000 || bufsize < 10 || N > 20 || N < 1 || R > 10 || R < 1){
        printf("Input is out of range!\n");
        return 0;
    }

    // create buffer
    buffer = (char* ***)malloc((N+1) * sizeof(char* **));
    for(i = 0; i < (N+1); i++){
        buffer[i] = (char* **)malloc(R * sizeof(char* *));
        for(j = 0; j < R; j++){
            buffer[i][j] = (char* *)malloc(bufsize * sizeof(char*));
            for(k = 0; k < bufsize; k++){
                buffer[i][j][k] = (char*)malloc(WORD_LENGTH * sizeof(char));
            }
        }
    }

    // buffer info. see decleration for explaination
    buffer_info = (int* **)malloc((N+1) * sizeof(int* *));
    for(i = 0; i < (N+1); i++){
        buffer_info[i] = (int* *)malloc(R * sizeof(int*));
        for(j = 0; j < R; j++){
            buffer_info[i][j] = (int* )malloc(4 * sizeof(int));
            for(k = 0; k < 4; k++){
                buffer_info[i][j][k] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    // create mutex
    mutex = (pthread_mutex_t* *)malloc((N+1) * sizeof(pthread_mutex_t*));
    for(i = 0; i < (N+1); i++){
        mutex[i] = (pthread_mutex_t*)malloc(R * sizeof(pthread_mutex_t));
        for(j = 0; j < R; j++){
            mutex[i][j] = (pthread_mutex_t) PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
        }
    }

    // create cond vars
    c_empty = (pthread_cond_t* *)malloc((N+1) * sizeof(pthread_cond_t*));
    for(i = 0; i < (N+1); i++){
        c_empty[i] = (pthread_cond_t*)malloc(R * sizeof(pthread_cond_t));
        for(j = 0; j < R; j++){
            c_empty[i][j] = (pthread_cond_t) PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
        }
    }
    c_fill = (pthread_cond_t* *)malloc((N+1) * sizeof(pthread_cond_t*));
    for(i = 0; i < (N+1); i++){
        c_fill[i] = (pthread_cond_t*)malloc(R * sizeof(pthread_cond_t));
        for(j = 0; j < R; j++){
            c_fill[i][j] = (pthread_cond_t) PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
        }
    }

    // create mapper threads
    pthread_t tids[N];
    struct arg args[N];

    for(i=0; i<N; i++){
        args[i].index = i;
        args[i].file_name = input_files[i];
        ret = pthread_create(&(tids[i]), NULL, &mapper, (void *) &args[i]);
        if (ret != 0) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    for(i=0; i<N; i++){
        ret = pthread_join(tids[i], NULL);  
        if (ret != 0) {
            printf("thread join failed \n");
            return 0;
        }
    }

    // create reducer threads
    pthread_t tids_r[R];
    int args_r[R];

    for(i=0; i<R; i++){
        // either pass the addresses of array elements, or allocate new memory 
        // in each iteration and pass the address. otherwise, we have memory problems.
        args_r[i] = i;
        ret = pthread_create(&(tids_r[i]), NULL, &reducer, (void *) &args_r[i]);
        if (ret != 0) {
            printf("thread create failed \n");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    for(i=0; i<R; i++){
        ret = pthread_join(tids_r[i], NULL);    
        if (ret != 0) {
            printf("thread join failed \n");
            return 0;
        }
    }

    // create merger thread
    pthread_t tid;
    ret = pthread_create(&tid, NULL, &merger, NULL);
    if (ret != 0) {
        printf("thread create failed \n");
        return 0;
    }   
    ret = pthread_join(tid, NULL);   
    if (ret != 0) {
        printf("thread join failed \n");
        return 0;
    }


    // freeing
    for(i = 0; i < (N+1); i++){
        for(j = 0; j < R; j++){
            for(k = 0; k < bufsize; k++){
                free(buffer[i][j][k]);
            }
            free(buffer[i][j]);
            free(buffer_info[i][j]);
        }
        free(buffer[i]);
        free(buffer_info[i]);
        free(mutex[i]);
        free(c_empty[i]);
        free(c_fill[i]);
    }
    free(buffer);
    free(buffer_info);
    free(mutex);
    free(c_empty);
    free(c_fill);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do not remove code from questions after receiving an answer.

Answer (score 3):

- I note the code returns silently when a memory allocation fails (`if(!newPtr) return;`), but `printf()`s (to `stdout`) and then exits the whole process when a file operation fails. Neither of these seem like sensible error-handling strategies. In particular, errors are supposed to be put on `stderr` and not on `stdout`. What if this is called from a batch process?
- Strongly consider defining a `struct` that holds both an `int * bufferInfo` and the `char ** buffer` and a mutex amd the two `pthread_cond_t`s, then make a two-dimensional array of that. That way you can guarantee that they match, reduce array lookups, and duplicated code, and alloc/free in one fell swoop.
- What's the point of the other `printf`s? Are they just for logging/diagnostic purposes?
- `merger()` is much too long. It would be much more readable if you broke its functionality up into separate functions
- In the body of the `while`, do you mean to set `min_i` to `-1` and then immediately check if it's `-1`? That seems pointless.